# How can I subscribe to ERC20 balance changes

Tags: ethereum

I want to "listen" to a specific ERC20 address balance changes. I can fetch the address's current balance using `balanceOf`, but from that moment I need to know about changes.

How can this be done? should I listen to the `Transfer` event. If so, how can I know the balance when I get the event.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since retrieving data from Ethereum doesn't cost you any gas, I think the simplest way is to call `balanceOf` when you detect a `Transfer` event with that specific address equals to `from` or `to` field.

Comment: Can you give an example on how to do just that?